# shared_ptr<Base> and objects from derived classes

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

Given something like this:

```
class Base {...};
class D1 : public Base {...};
class D2 : public Base {...};
```

In my code, is it legal to use `std::shared_ptr<Base>` to manage the lifetime and pass around objects of types `D1` and `D2`?  Or could this cause a world of pain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is completely fine. Smart pointers are designed to be drop-in replacements for dump pointers.

Of course you have to think about whether to make Base's member functions `virtual`, just like you would with dumb pointers.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I guess *raw pointer* would be the term defined in the standard, but dump pointer has a nicer ring to it :)

Answer (score 2):

If the following is possible to do

```
Base* ptr_base = new Derived()
```

Then the following should also be true

```
std::shared_ptr<Derived> ptr_derived = std::make_shared<Derived>();
std::shared_ptr<Base> ptr_base = ptr_derived;
// The shared pointer count is 2 as logically there are 2 handles to
// to the same memory object.
```

After this the base shared pointer can be used for run-time polymorphism as we used to use raw pointers for the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly ok if your classes are designed for polymorphism.

If your classes are not polymorphic (i.e. no virtual members), this construct could require additional work (every object would be handled as if it were a Base object when you'd invoke member functions). In this case you'd better use `std::shared_ptr<Base>`,  `std::shared_ptr<D1>`, `std::shared_ptr<D2>`... and [`static_pointer_cast<>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/static_pointer_cast/) when needed.

Comment: @KerrekSB ok, you could pass over a deleter to overcome a non virtual destructor.  Nevertheless, for any non virtual function, if you'd invoke sp->myfunction(), it would always be Base::myfunction(), unless explicit tedious and error prone downcasting.

Comment: @KerrekSB you're right about the destructor. i've edited the answer accordingly.  Nevertheless, I think the rest remains valid.